# How to divide two aggreate sum dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I want to divide the sum of two columns in ***pyspark***. For example, I have a datasets like below:

```
    A  B  C
 1  1  2  3
 2  1  2  3
 3  1  2  3
```

What I want is to get sum of `colA` divide by sum of `colB` as below:

```
  6 (Sum of colB)  / 3 (Sum of colA) = 2
```

I have tried this:

```
sumofA = df.groupby().sum('A') 
sumofB = df.groupby().sum('B')

Result = B / A
```

but it produces this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'DataFrame' and 'DataFrame'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach was correct, but you could just do the calculation **inside the aggregation function** only.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.groupBy().agg(F.sum("B")/F.sum("A")).show()
+-----------------+
|(sum(B) / sum(A))|
+-----------------+
|              2.0|
+-----------------+
```

OR, you can **collect** it as a **value** using `collect()[0][0]`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
a=df.groupBy().agg(F.sum("B")/F.sum("A")).collect()[0][0]
a

Out[5]: 2.0
```